# Javascript: passing keypress event to an iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a basic HTML design with an IFRAME in it, and if I want to work the scrolling with arrows/page up,down, first I have to focus the iframe. Instead, I want to "forward" the keypress events to it. In :

```
<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    top.frames['iframe'].document.onkeypress(e);
}
</script>
```

but this doesnt work. **I must not use jQuery!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a new feature in HTML5, "window.postMessage", which allows for communication between an iFrame and the hosting window.

There's some good documentation on the [Mozilla Developer Center - window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) page.

```
//Syntax
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

Comment: Good answer, although it's not that new. HTML5 has been around for quite some time now, and hopefully everyone is using it and not languishing in outdated technologies. :)

Comment: Haha hopefully everyone is using HTML5 :)